# typescript can i use class like interface

Tags: typescript

I have this code:

```
interface Heroe {
    title:string,
    hero:string,
    ranking:number,
}

export class AppComponent {
  heroe : Heroe = {
     title : 'Tour of Heroes',
     hero : 'Windstorm',
     ranking :1
  }
}
```

if I replace Class instead Interface code works:

```
class Heroe {
    title:string,
    hero:string,
    ranking:number,
}

export class AppComponent {
  heroe : Heroe = {
     title : 'Tour of Heroes',
     hero : 'Windstorm',
     ranking :1
  }
}
```

It's correct to use class like interfaces, when class have no methods, just type of variables, that is not a problem?. In angular demo use this way, have a class and not interface:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html

in this last case I have a class instead Interface, and have no interface for the class,

the correct would not be have Interface first, then a  Class based in the interface ? , but if both have the same name; how typescript which must use ??

Example:

```
interface Heroe {
    title:string,
    hero:string,
    ranking:number,
}
class Heroe  interface Heroe {
    title:string,
    hero:string,
    ranking:number,
}

export class AppComponent {
  heroe : Heroe = {
     title : 'Tour of Heroes',
     hero : 'Windstorm',
     ranking :1
  }
}
```

I's ok too have Heroe same name class like interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"It's correct to use class like interfaces"
Well, that depends on what you're trying to do, but it's not the same:

```
class Heroe {
    title: string;
    hero: string;
    ranking: number;

    constructor(title: string, hero: string, ranking: number) {
        this.title = title;
        this.hero = hero;
        this.ranking = ranking;
    }
}

let o1 = new Heroe("title", "hero", 0);
let o2: Heroe = { title: "title", hero: "hero", ranking: 0 }
```

compiles into:

```
var Heroe = (function () {
    function Heroe(title, hero, ranking) {
        this.title = title;
        this.hero = hero;
        this.ranking = ranking;
    }
    return Heroe;
}());
var o1 = new Heroe("title", "hero", 0);
var o2 = { title: "title", hero: "hero", ranking: 0 };
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Heroe%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20title%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20hero%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ranking%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09constructor(title%3A%20string%2C%20hero%3A%20string%2C%20ranking%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.title%20%3D%20title%3B%0D%0A%09%09this.hero%20%3D%20hero%3B%0D%0A%09%09this.ranking%20%3D%20ranking%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20o1%20%3D%20new%20Heroe(%22title%22%2C%20%22hero%22%2C%200)%3B%0D%0Alet%20o2%3A%20Heroe%20%3D%20%7B%20title%3A%20%22title%22%2C%20hero%3A%20%22hero%22%2C%20ranking%3A%200%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(o1)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Heroe%20%7Btitle%3A%20%22title%22%2C%20hero%3A%20%22hero%22%2C%20ranking%3A%200%7D%0D%0Aconsole.log(o2)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Object%20%7Btitle%3A%20%22title%22%2C%20hero%3A%20%22hero%22%2C%20ranking%3A%200%7D))

As you can see `o1` and `o2` are clearly different, one is an instance of the `Heroe` class and the second is just an object with the same properties as the instance.

It's clear in the console:

```
console.log(o1); // Heroe {title: "title", hero: "hero", ranking: 0}
console.log(o2); // Object {title: "title", hero: "hero", ranking: 0}
```

The reason that the compiler doesn't care that `o2` is just an object even when declared as `Heroe` [is because](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#introduction):

> One of TypeScript’s core principles is that type-checking focuses on
>   the shape that values have. This is sometimes called “duck typing” or
>   “structural subtyping”.

([more about Duck typing](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Duck_typing))

Or with an example:

```
function log(heroe: Heroe) {
    console.log(`Title: ${ heroe.title }, Hero: ${ heroe.hero }, Ranking: ${ heroe.ranking }`);
}

log(o1); // obviously this is ok
log(o2); // but this is ok as well
```

Passing `o2` is fine because even if it's not an instance of `Heroe` it does satisfy the interface for the class.

---

You can use the same name for an interface and a class, but you can't redeclare properties, so this is not ok:

```
interface Heroe {
    title: string; // Error: Duplicate identifier 'title'
}

class Heroe {
    title: string; // Error: Duplicate identifier 'title'
}
```

But this is:

interface Heroe {
    title: string;
}

class Heroe {
    subtitle: string;
}

The order of the declarations doesn't matter, you can have the interface below the class.
You can read more about this in [Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).

But you can also implement an interface:

```
interface IHeroe {
    title: string;
    hero: string;
    ranking: number;
}

class Heroe implements IHeroe {
    title: string;
    hero: string;
    ranking: number;
}
```

Comment: what a great answer!